# How to make a counter which changes version number after each recompile

Tags: counters

I am pretty new to Overleaf, I struggle a lot and learn a lot too. For a specific problem, I did not find a solution, and even if there is something online, I hardly understand how to implement it, but all of the aside, here is the problem!

I need a counter which updates the document version number after each recompile session
[image: This document version]
from 0.00.1a -> 0.00.2a and so on.

If somebody can help me with this, it will mean a lot!

Comment: such a counter is inherently unstable, you could write to the aux file and increment each time, but if the generated files cache is cleared or you have an error that prevents the aux being written you will start again from 0

Comment: why do you want the version to change if you just recompile an unchanged file? if it takes 4 runs to resolve all `\ref` do you want the version to start at 4?

Comment: Company policy haha!

Comment: Welcome. // For my understanding: what is it good for? E.g. I compiled so frequently, it will have no useful meaning to me. But it may be different for you. // Or do you look for versioning? Then dig into git OR https://ctan.org/pkg/version.

Comment: It's important to keep a recompile count for a reason! Now, what that reason is I can not truly share with you as I do not have the answer to that. But what I do know is that I must make this work!

Comment: No that surely can't be company policy isn't the policy that each new version you distrbute has a new version? You can set overleaf to continuously recompile in the background as you edit, do you want the version number to auto-increment with no human intervention?

Comment: If you have the paid-for account you can tie your source file to git so count commits, if writing to a file on each tex run there is always a danger it will reset to 0 and the number will increase in a meaningless way, but I could post how to do that if you really mean that

Comment: The plan is for me to manually do the recompiling each time I feel like it is necessary. Please do not worry about the number being too high

Comment: Please do so, I will have a look

Answer (score 1):

I can not see this being useful in practice but an incrementing number in the aux file

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\ifx\thisnumber\undefined\gdef\thisnumber{1}\fi
\immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\noexpand\thisnumber{\the\numexpr\thisnumber+1}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Version: \thisnumber

\end{document}
```

Comment: on overleaf this goes up in steps of 5, as it runs that often, you  could probably reduce that by using a dedicated file but still latexmk will do multiple runs to resolve cross refs.